# particular part of non-linear second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, mathematical-physics, general-relativity, nonlinear-analysis

I ma trying to find a solution for the following ODE:

$$y''+p y'+q y=r y^{2},$$

where prime depicts the derivative with respect to $x$ and $p$, $q$ and $r$ are constant. The left side of the equation is the linear and can be found as a general solution

$$y=c_{1}e^{m_{1}x}+c_{2}e^{m_{2}x},$$

but i don't know how can I specify a function corresponding to the right side to find the particular solution.

Comment: The equation is autonomous. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Autonomous.html

Comment: Your equation is homogeneous, so it doesn't have a particular solution. Your 'general solution' $y = c_{1}e^{m_{1}x} + \dots$ doesn't satisfy the equation because while the LHS vanishes, the right hand side doesn't.